# Is there a way to get possible characters for a image (containing single character) in tesseract?

Tags: tesseract

I tried searching around in the internet, github issues and such, but was unable to find if it's possible to get the result with different possible character alternatives while using tesseract.

for example while running `tesseract -l jpn --psm 10 input.png -` on this image [image] I get the output `白`, but if possible I'd like to also see the other possibilities, and if possible with their confidence coefficients.

I found that it's specially useful while trying to recognize a single character as the tesseract --psm 10 will give wrong but close results for complex kanji.

Like [image] was being recognized as 側. So, I was thinking if I could like get the 5 most probable or sth like that from the command line, then it could be great. And if it's not possible through the command line I'm also willing to see a direct programming approach using the API.

EDIT:
`tesseract -l jpn --psm 10 iu.png -` command on [image] results in `雨` result. On doing this on the code given in [the answer](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/master/APIExample.md#example-of-iterator-over-the-classifier-choices-for-a-single-symbol) I can see that the confidence is `93.68%` and shows only one result. If I run the same in this image instead [image], I'll get `言 (99.46%)` which means it is giving a sensible result, but it's only giving me a single result ignoring others. I hypothesized that it does so because the confidence is high because if I run the same command on [image], I get `遊` but when I run the code, I get

```
遊 (71.77%)
遮 (67.41%)
遭 (66.76%)
避 (65.36%)
遷 (65.00%)
選 (64.70%)
透 (64.55%)
進 (64.52%)
適 (63.95%)
週 (63.22%)
```

Hence, I assume it's giving single result in previous images because it is confident.

Furthermore doing `tesseract -l jpn_vert screenshot.png -` in this image [image] gives the output `言わない`, which is correct, which means even when it gave me `雨` result on the cropped character in the same image, there was `言` match there but with lower coefficient but it came up when it was doing the dictionary match in the whole word (which removed `雨` as a possibility). That's why while trying to identify a single character, I want to get the output with all those matches (a fixed number or a threshold decided by myself).

The code I have is almost identical to the one given in the example I have only added whitelist characters (around 2000+ kanji). Had to remove `api->SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", ...)` line because SO thought it was spam.

```cpp
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>
#include <tesseract/publictypes.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
// Initialize tesseract-ocr with Japanese, without specifying tessdata path
    if (api->Init(NULL, "jpn")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
// Open input image with leptonica library
  Pix *image = pixRead(argv[1]);
  api->SetImage(image);
  api->SetVariable("save_blob_choices", "T");
  api->SetPageSegMode(tesseract::PSM_SINGLE_CHAR);
  api->Recognize(NULL);

  tesseract::ResultIterator* ri = api->GetIterator();
  tesseract::PageIteratorLevel level = tesseract::RIL_SYMBOL;
  if(ri != 0) {
      do {
          const char* symbol = ri->GetUTF8Text(level);
          float conf = ri->Confidence(level);
          if(symbol != 0) {
              tesseract::ChoiceIterator ci(*ri);
              do {
                  const char* choice = ci.GetUTF8Text();
                  printf("%s (%.2f%%)\n", choice, ci.Confidence());
              } while(ci.Next());
          }
          delete[] symbol;
      } while((ri->Next(level)));
  }
// Destroy used object and release memory
    api->End();
    pixDestroy(&image);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you will need to use tesseract API https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/master/APIExample.md#example-of-iterator-over-the-classifier-choices-for-a-single-symbol

Comment: I accepted it as it does help me, but a slight problem I encountered, this doesn't seem to always give the alternatives, specially when it has higher confidence for a character (but wrong). If it gets a correct one with just 75% confidence it'll give alternatives, but it gets something wrong but has 95+ confidence then it won't give any other. At least that's how it went when I tried it on a ubuntu server. I also tried to whitelist to limit the possible character but that just made it give empty result.

Comment: Word description does not help. Provide minimal code and input image for problem description.

Comment: The code is almost an exact copy of the example you have that's why I didn't put it. I have edited the question with more details of examples and few pictures. 

If it's all confusing just try that code and try to get more than 1 alternative character even when the confidence of the character recognition is above 95% you can use any characters even English one and the code is right there, that should suffice. I tried to go through the variables in the tesseract by `setVariable` method to see if I can change the threshold but I didn't find any.